# How to send user to Facebook page on button click

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ibaction

I'm new to iOS development so please bear with me..

I'm in the process of creating a simple app. There is a facebook button and I'd like that button to send the user to my facebook page, either in the browser or if they have the facebook app open that up.

I know there's probably a lot to explain, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks.

Comment: I like the humble tone of your question. Especially that last sentence makes it clear that you do not expect a full blown `gimme teh codez`- solution. I Like +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the 4.0 update for Facebook, you can jump to pages with this URI schema:

```
fb://page/{fbid}
```

Just make sure you check to make sure that the device you're working with can respond to it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"fb://page/{fbid}"]];
```

Your method might end up looking something like this:

```
- (IBAction)openFBPage:(id)sender {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"fb://page/{fbid}"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"fb://page/{fbid}"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Facebook isn't installed.");
        // or do the sensible thing and openURL the HTTP version of the page in safari
}
```

... and you'd link the above method with your button in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the FacebookSDK and follow the steps that are described over there. Check out this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Hope helps...

Comment: Not exactly what OP's describing.